# Rails, with an Edit button open a modal, pass the @article parameter and populate fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a form in a modal for creating an article which works just fine:

```
<%=form_for @article, url: articles_create_path,remote: true, html: {class: "form-horizontal"} do |f|%>

  <fieldset class="content-group">
  <legend class="text-bold">Images</legend>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-2 text-semibold">Main image:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.file_field :image, :class => 'file-input-custom', 'data-show-caption' => true, 'data-show-upload' => false, :accept => 'image/*'%>
    </div>
  </div>

  </fieldset>
  <%= f.fields_for :strings do |fa| %>
    <fieldset class="content-group">
      <legend class="text-bold">Localization</legend>
        <div class="tabbable">

            <div class="tab-content">
              <% @languages.each do |lang| %>
                <%= fa.fields_for lang.id.to_s do |fb| %>

                  <div class="tab-pane active" id="basic-justified-tab-<%= lang.id %>">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-lg-2 control-label text-semibold"><%= lang.name %> Title: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                      <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <%= fb.text_field :title, :class => 'form-control', :required => 'required' %>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="title" class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1"><%= lang.name %> Text:</label>
                      <%= fb.text_area :text, :style => "height: 250px;", :class => 'wysihtml5 wysihtml5-min form-control', :required => 'required' %>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <hr>

                <% end %>
              <% end %>
              </div>
            </div>

    </fieldset>
  <% end %>                              

<div class="form-group">

  <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-8">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" >
  </div>

</div>

<% end %>
```

Later I create a table of all my **articles**:

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
        <% if article.type = "news" %>
            <div class="panel panel-flat">

                <table class="table datatable-basic table-hover">
                    <tbody>                         
                            <tr>
                            <td rowspan="4" style="width:200px;"><%= image_tag article.image_url(:thumb) %> </td>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>
                                Text 
                                <span style="float:right">
                                    <%=button_to("Delete", { url: "articles#destroy"}, {method: :delete, remote: true,
                                            :class => "btn btn-danger", :onclick => "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this article?')"})%>                                               
                                </span>
                                <span style="float:right; margin-right:7px">
                                    <%= button_to("Edit",{ controller: 'articles', action: 'destroy', id: article.id}, { remote: true, :class => "btn btn-info edit"}) %>

                                </span>

                            </th>                           
                            <% article.article_localizations.each do |localization| %>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><%= localization.title unless localization.blank? %></td>
                                    <td><%= localization.text unless localization.blank? %></td>
                                </tr>
                            <% end %>
                            </tr>                                                   
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Now what I want to do is:

When I click "Edit" on an article I want a modal with a similar form popup and to be populated with the article's fields.
I could populate it with javascript but it doesn't feel Rails-y.

From what I searched this can be done but first I must somehow pass the **@article** parameter to the modal when I click the Edit button.

Is there a smart and simple solution to this?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Let me see if i get what you want... u want an edit on Article that opens a form for another model but populates with the data of the article?

Comment: @Boltz0r Yes, exactly. I was thinking of searching by article id and populating the modal with javascript on clicking "Edit", but is there a better way than this?

Comment: i would suggest creating a new action calling the same form %=form_for @article but in the action controller u use the data for the other modal... you will have no problems with that

Comment: I actually did what you said and worked and I forgot to thank you last week, so... Thanks!